# jQuery is not defined although the script is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know this subject was heavily discussed, but I don't seem to find a solution.

I try to load several libs in callbacks, like this:

```
var loadjQuery = function (){
    console.log('loadjQuery');
    try {
        jQuery();
        loadLocalStorage();
    } catch(e) {
        var jq = document.createElement('script');
        jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        jq.src = '//myurl/assets/js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.js';
        jq.onload = function (){ $.noConflict();};
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
        try {
            jQuery();
            loadLocalStorage();
        } catch (e) {
            jq.src = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js';
            jq.onload = function (){ $.noConflict();};
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
            loadLocalStorage();
        }

    }   
}
var loadCookie = function (){
    console.log('loadCookie');
    try { 
        jQuery.cookie();
    } catch(e) { 
        var cook = document.createElement('script'); 
        cook.type = 'text/javascript';
        cook.src = '//myurl/assets/js/lib/jquery.cookie.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(cook); 
    }
}
var loadLocalStorage = function (){
    console.log('loadLocalStorage');
    try { 
        jQuery.localStorage();
        loadCookie();
    } catch(e) { 
        var ls = document.createElement('script'); 
        ls.type = 'text/javascript';
        ls.src = '//myurl/assets/js/lib/jquery.storage.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(ls);
        loadCookie();
    }
}

loadjQuery ();
```

The files are all loaded in the network whit 200 response. The code is loaded as well. 
But when I try to use the code I get :

```
jQuery is not defined
```

If I go to the error in file jquery.storage.js for example, I get error on this line:

```
}(jQuery, window, document));
```

I went over all of the answers to this subject. Put the script in the header and in the footer. Set  defer="defer" etc'... What am I missing?

Comment: Take the defer off.  defer makes the load happen asynchronously.  If your script requires jQuery to be loaded, then you cannot defer it.

Comment: I think it is better to switch the line `jq.onload` with `jq.src`. Because the `onload` handler might not be invoked.

Comment: @YonggooNoh I think it's not invoked as well, but I don't know why. 
I make the change - no luck.

Comment: @matisa It is just a side note for you, not the solution of this question. :)

Comment: Why load your basic libraries like jQuery asynchronously? It will just everything to have to be put into callbacks and be less maintainable/readable perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this was so stupid. 
Because js works asynchronously, although all the scripts were loaded in the right order and I could use jQuery in console and after document ready, the libraries didn't init because the jQuery was not loaded yet at this point.

The trick was to add the callback in the onload function, like this:

```
var loadjQuery = function (){
    console.log('loadjQuery');
    try {
        jQuery();
        loadLocalStorage();
    } catch(e) {
        var jq = document.createElement('script');
        jq.type = 'text/javascript';
        jq.onload = function (){ 
        $.noConflict();
        loadLocalStorage();
        loadCookie();
        };
        jq.src = '//myurl/assets/js/lib/jquery-2.1.1.js';
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);   
    }
```

}

Comment: Catch blocks should probably just be used to handle exceptions, and not be a standard part of your code's flow.

Comment: Actually in this case it is used to check if angular is already loaded to prevent double load.